# Error in HttpURLConnection - openConnection

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpconnection

I am having the following java function for check the website responce code:

```
URL u = null;   

try {
    u = new URL("http://bforball.com");
    HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection ) u.openConnection (); 
    huc.setRequestMethod ("GET"); 
    huc.connect () ; 
}
```

I have imported the below:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

But when I compile my code I am getting warning message near

> u.openConnection

Warning message:

```
Connot find the symbol
Symbol: mehod openConnection()
Location:variable u of type URL
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you declare `URL u;` before that code?

Comment: Yes i have declaration as `URL u = null;`

Comment: Do you have any other class named `URL` in the same package as this class ? Seems you are using the intended class `java.net.URL`

Comment: I am having java.net.* is this enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have wrong import on `URL` class. You have to import URL with correct package :

```
import java.net.URL;
```

It has method `openConnection()`

Comment: I have tested your code provided and it has no compile error. Try to do something like this : `java.net.URL u = new URL("http://google.com")`

Comment: import java.net.URL; This import package works for me .ThakYou

Answer (score 1):

Check your `import` for the URL class. It should be

```
import java.net.URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe URL class which you used doesn't have an openConnection() method?

Comment: It does. At least the java.net.URL one.